# Select from two tables with same columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to tables, each with 4 columns (id, name, games, points). The column-names are the same in both tables. I would like to select everything from both columns in one big table (like if in soccer, you joined the MLS and Premier League in one table). 
I've tried this code:

```
SELECT * FROM league1 JOIN league 2;
```

but it wasn't the output I wanted. 
I can see my tables aren't created exatly the same:

```
CREATE TABLE `league1` (
 `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Navn` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
 `kampe` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Point` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC

CREATE TABLE `league2` (
 `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Navn` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `kampe` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Point` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Isn't it possible to join them under the same columns, so I still have the 4 columns but all the rows from both tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all` to keep duplicates. And in case the number of field are different you can just declare the field matching on both tables instead of `*`

```
  SELECT * FROM league1 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM league2
```

Comment: If I write this in mysql it says: #1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'

Comment: Looks like your tables arent that `"equal"`  after all?  Update your question to show the create table for each league. But seem like you have to do a `CAST` so  both table have same date type.

Comment: Maybe you're right .. Stupid question, but can I find the `create table` somewhere, because it's a long ago I created it.

Comment: You can use [**SHOW CREATE TABLE**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html)

Comment: Thank you. Just updated my question. You were right, not exactly the same.. Can I fix that now or should I create new tables?

Comment: You can change the collate in the table `ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name [COLLATE collation_name];`  Now dont know if you want change the one default to danish or the danish to the default.

Comment: But that is for another question, try to do the `UNION` specify the columns without the `Navn`

Comment: So can I just put `ALTER TABLE league1 CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET default;` or should I give it a charset name? Sorry, not so good at this :)

Comment: Jep, it worked without `Navn`. So that's because of the charset name?

Comment: Yes. Just try to change the character set, or google for change column collation. But be carefull dont know danish. But if you change to default you may get weird chars.

Comment: I got it!! :D Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to join but to unite the content of the two tables

```
SELECT  *
FROM    league1 
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    league2;
```